# getFieldSpec_original in PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, session, server-side

I have been searching for documentation about storing PHP sessions in Database so that users can control their current active sessions and I stumbled upon something like this inside a class method: `$this->getFieldSpec_original();`.

`getFieldSpec_original()` is not defined inside that class and I don't understand what that method is (without being anywhere inside that class besides one place). Can anyone explain this? Also if anyone has a good place where I can research about this PHP Sessions thing I mentioned about, I would be thankful.

Comment: Maybe from RADICORE for PHP : http://www.tonymarston.co.uk/php-mysql/functions-and-variables.html#notes.getfieldspec_original

Comment: @PaulF That is true, I just found it. Is there any way to close this post?

Comment: @DenisMakula, write the answer if you have got it.